# C++ custom exception class

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception, c++20

I am wondering, how can I improve this simple `MissingResource` exception class? I am using it in my simple game.

```
template <typename Resource>
class MissingResource : public std::exception {
    std::string_view fileName{};
    std::string_view msg{};
    
public:
    MissingResource() = default;
    MissingResource(std::string_view fileName)
    : fileName{fileName}
    {
        initMsg<Resource>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void initMsg() {
        msg = "Failed loading resource: "
              "{ Type: "    + std::string(typeid(Resource).name()) + ", "
              "File name: " + fileName.data()                      + " }";
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.data();
    }
};
```

Throw usage:

```
template <typename Key, typename Resource>
#if (__cplusplus == 202002L)
  requires Mappable<Key>
#endif
class ResourceHolder {
    std::unordered_map<Key, std::unique_ptr<Resource>> resources;
    std::string resourcesDir;

public:

    explicit ResourceHolder(std::string_view resourcesDir = "../resources/")
            : resourcesDir{std::move(resourcesDir)}
    {}

    template <typename... Args>
    void insert(const Key& key, std::string_view fileName, Args&&... args) {
        auto resPtr = std::make_unique<Resource>();

        bool loaded{};
        if constexpr (std::is_same<Resource, sf::Music>()) {
            loaded = resPtr->openFromFile(resourcesDir + fileName.data(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            loaded = resPtr->loadFromFile(resourcesDir + fileName.data(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        /** Called here */
        if (!loaded) {
            throw MissingResource<Resource>(fileName);
        }
        resources.emplace(key, std::move(resPtr));
}
```

Try-Catch usage:

```
ResourceManager::ResourceManager() {
    try {
        loadResources();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Exemplary error message:

```
what():  Failed loading resource: { Type: N2sf11SoundBufferE, File name: Death.wav }
```

P.S: If you see some smelly code or have doubts or found any kind of other mistakes, I would be looking forward to knowing them. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised that none of the answers mention that you shouldn't derive from std::exception directly, but rather from std::runtime_error or similar. But maybe I'm just wrong.

Comment: @sbecker, I don't see the benefit of deriving from `std::runtime_error` in this case. `std::exception` is an abstract class, and he wants to override `what` basically.  Maybe he can remove some code if inheriting from `std::runtime_error` (removing string member), but I think the class is clear enough as it is. Inheritance chains don't need to be unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`std::string_view`**

Firstly, there seems to be some *misusages* of `string_view`. `string_view` is non-owning, and is a view to an allocated char array (such as `string`).

The usage

```
template <typename Resource>
class MissingResource : public std::exception {
    std::string_view fileName{};
    std::string_view msg{};
    
public:
    [...]
    template <typename T>
    void initMsg() {
        msg = "Failed loading resource: "
              "{ Type: "    + std::string(typeid(Resource).name()) + ", "
              "File name: " + fileName.data()                      + " }";
    }
    [...]
};
```

Is dangerous, since after calling `initMsg()`, msg will point to an destroyed object (the right hand string is temporary).

Better change it to be an owning string in this case: `std::string_view msg` => `std::string msg`. I assume you already have it like this, otherwise it would provide the output which you gave in the description.

Secondly, the other member variable `std::string_view fileName` does not seem *necessary*. Since you create the error message for `msg` with `fileName` and do not use alone, we can skip it, right?

**General design of `MissingResource`**

Applying the changes above, we have:

```
template <typename Resource>
class MissingResource : public std::exception {
    std::string msg{};
    
public:
    MissingResource() = default;
    MissingResource(std::string_view fileName)
    {
        initMsg<Resource>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void initMsg(std::string_view fileName) {
        msg = "Failed loading resource: "
              "{ Type: "    + std::string(typeid(Resource).name()) + ", "
              "File name: " + fileName.data()                      + " }";
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.data();
    }
};
```

`initMsg` is currently a *public method*, but from what I see, it's only used locally in the constructor. If this is the case, it should rather be a *private method* - you want to keep the public API for the class as simple and small as possible.

Another improvement would be to be able to create `msg` in the constructor list - so that it does not have to be created twice. We can do this by making the initMsg a static method.

Let's remove the extra unnecessary template for initMsg as well - the entire class already holds the template argument.

And note that virtual + override is *unnecessary*. If you mark a method as overrided, it is implicitly virtual. Remove virtual for unnecessary noise.

We now have something like this:

```
template <typename Resource>
class MissingResource : public std::exception {
    std::string msg{};

    static std::string initMsg(std::string_view fileName) {
        return "Failed loading resource: "
              "{ Type: "    + std::string(typeid(Resource).name()) + ", "
              "File name: " + fileName.data()                      + " }";
    }
    
public:
    MissingResource() = default;
    MissingResource(std::string_view fileName) : msg{initMsg<Resource>()}
    {}

    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.data();
    }
};
```

**`ResourceHolder`**

Since this review is already long, I will just point out one thing in `ResourceHolder`, namely in `insert`. We can avoid separating declaration from initialization for bool loaded (and make it const!) by encapsulating the logic into a separate method. This might be a bit preferential, but it is good practice to avoid separating declaration and initialization.

Something like this:

```
private:
    bool fromFile(std::string_view fileName, Args&&... args) 
    {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<Resource, sf::Music>()) {
            return resPtr->openFromFile(resourcesDir + fileName.data(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } 
    else {
            return resPtr->loadFromFile(resourcesDir + fileName.data(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void insert(const Key& key, std::string_view fileName, Args&&... args) {
        auto resPtr = std::make_unique<Resource>();
    
        const bool loaded = fromFile(fileName, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        
        /** Called here */
        if (!loaded) {
            throw MissingResource<Resource>(fileName);
        }
        resources.emplace(key, std::move(resPtr));
    }
```

Comment: Came to say this. An easy rule of thumb is: use `std::string` to store and `std::string_view` to look/pass around.

Answer (score 4):

One problem I can see with your code is, that you can't catch `MissingResource` unless you know the specific `Resource` type used when that exception was thrown.
All you can do in the `catch` is to capture the generic `std::exception`, which is also the base for many other kinds of failure, including the stuff that's used from the c++ standard library.

A better way would be to introduce a specific base class for the whole category of `MissingResource` exceptions. E.g. like this:

```
class MissingResourceCategory : public std::exception {
protected:
    std::string_view fileName{};
    std::string_view msg{};

    MissingResourceCategory() = default;
};

template <typename Resource>
class MissingResource : public MissingResourceCategory {
    
public:
    MissingResource() = default;
    MissingResource(std::string_view fileName) : fileName{fileName} {
        initMsg<Resource>();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void initMsg() {
        msg = "Failed loading resource: "
              "{ Type: "    + std::string(typeid(Resource).name()) + ", "
              "File name: " + fileName.data()                      + " }";
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.data();
    }
};
```

This would allow you to distinguish `MissingResource` exceptions from others in your `catch` blocks:

```
ResourceManager::ResourceManager() {
    try {
        loadResources();
    } catch (const MissingResourceCategory& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_RESOURCE_FAILURE);
    }
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```